# Access $ionicConfigProvider in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a Separate file for my controller filename is ProfileController.js and I would like to change the text of the back button I search and I found this is the code `$ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('Go Back').icon('ion-chevron-left');` How can I access $ionicConfigProvider in my separate file controller.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inject `$ionicConfigProvider` into a controller but you can use `$ionicConfig` to achieve what you wish.

From the [$ionicConfigProvider docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/):

> These configs can be changed using the $ionicConfigProvider during the
>   configuration phase of your app. Additionally, $ionicConfig can also
>   set and get config values during the run phase and within the app
>   itself.

Comment: so I can just do $ionicConfig.backButton.text('Go Back').icon('ion-chevron-left') ?